# How do you make the turtles follow only the green patches that I created from a shapefile Ioaded into netlogo?

Tags: gis, netlogo

This is my code so far. I only want the turtles to follow the green lines, however they just continue forever in the random direction they are facing when I setup the model.

Code:

```
extensions [gis]
breed [observer]

turtles-own [ vision-distance vision-width steps green-steps gray-steps attr-prob]
patches-own [land nearest-patch]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  set-default-shape turtles "butterfly"
  ask turtles [set size 25
  if pxcor = min-pxcor [die]]
  reset-ticks
  let view gis:load-dataset "City_Plan_Boundary.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of view
  foreach gis:feature-list-of view
  [
    gis:set-drawing-color green
    gis:draw ? 1.0
  ]

end

to go
  ask turtles [
    count-steps

pen-down
    let green_target turtles
    let perceived_patches patches in-cone vision-distance vision-width
    let patch-under-me patch-here    set green_target perceived_patches with [ (pcolor = green and self != patch-under-me) or (pcolor = black and self != patch-under-me)]
    ifelse  count green_target != 0 [
          let target min-one-of green_target[ distance myself ]
          let target_heading towards target
          move-to patch-at-heading-and-distance target_heading 1 ]
          [ fd 1]

     ]


end

to count-steps
  set steps steps + 1
  ifelse land = green [set green-steps green-steps + 1][set gray-steps gray-steps + 1] ;;Does not currently account for CYAN Park squares
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `foreach` loop that applies your GIS layer is only creating lines in the [drawing layer](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#drawing) of NetLogo, not actually changing the patches themselves. You'll have to assign some component of the shapefile to the patches themselves for turtles to be able to assess them- look at the "GIS General Examples" model in the Models Library.

Second, pathfinding can be accomplished in a variety of ways, and it really depends on what behaviour you're trying to model. For a few examples, check out the "Look Ahead" example in the Models library, or look at the below toy model for a very simplistic approach:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask patch min-pxcor 0 [
    set pcolor green    
    sprout 1 [ 
      set color red 
      pd
    ]
    spread-right
  ] 
  reset-ticks
end

to spread-right 
  if pxcor < max-pxcor [
    ask one-of neighbors with [ pxcor = [pxcor] of myself + 1] [
      set pcolor green
      spread-right
    ]
  ]
end

to go 
  ask turtles [
    let target one-of neighbors in-cone 1.5 90 with [ pcolor = green ]
    ifelse target != nobody [
      face target
      move-to target
    ] [
      rt one-of [ 45 -45 ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So it is possible to make the patches the color that the shapefile is representing?

Comment: @Shane - Yes, you definitely can do that! I think you'll want the `gis-intersecting` primitive in the GIS extension, assuming your shapefiles include linear features.